# Windows Server 2003 can't find RAID array during install on Dell PowerEdge 2850

Tags: windows-server-2003, raid, installation, dell-poweredge

I'm trying to install Windows Server 2003 Web Edition on a Dell Poweredge 2850.

I've configured the RAID following these instructions:

http://lists.us.dell.com/pipermail/linux-poweredge/2007-August/032551.html

However - when i hit enter to install from the windows install media - it just says it can't find the disks. Is there anything above and beyond what is mentioned in that post or should this *just* *work* ?

[edit]
This was sorted using a streamlined driver install as suggested by DanBig - thanks guys :)

Comment: Every server manufacturer provides their own CD/DVD for such installations, IBM - SERVERGUID, HP - SMARTSTART, Dell - don't recall the name. Just download it from manufacturer's website.

Comment: I'm trying out Dell OpenManage - this is not as easy as the HP server i installed this morning!

Comment: Maybe, however documentation available on the DELL's site on how to  use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need the RAID driver. When you boot from the Windows installation CD it will ask you to press F6 for drivers. Hit F6 and have your RAID driver available on a floppy.

At this point you should see your configured array and be able to install or partition as necessary.

Since you do not have a floppy drive, the only other way to get drivers loaded is to slipstream them into the installation, and burn a new install CD/DVD. Check out [nLite](http://www.nliteos.com/) to get this done.

Or, install Server 2008, which will most likely have the driver in it's list.

EDIT: As others have mentioned, you could also use the Dell recovery disc that came with the server, or order one from Dell.

Comment: floppy... yeah... about that!! :s any other way of getting the driver in there?

Comment: You may be able to slipstream a new installation disk with the driver, but thats about it. Unless windows has the driver available on the disk, it will only look to a floppy.

Comment: what about burning it to a cd and swapping it out during install?

Comment: Nope, needs to be found during the scan of the installation CD, and if not found there, will only go to floppy.

Comment: It would probably be quicker to bogart a floppy drive from a nearby desktop machine than bothering with anything else.

Comment: that's the issue - i dont have a floppy, nor a machine witha  floppy :(

Comment: See the edit. Unfortunately, its slipstream or nothing.

Comment: Places like best buy sell USB floppy drives and floppy disks.  You can get them for around $50 USD.

Comment: going for 2008 :)

Comment: Would i need to initialize the partitions above what was stated in that post?

Comment: Is there a Dell server setup CD?  That usually bypasses all this floppy disk razzmatazz.

Comment: nah - trying with openmanage now... i'll rpt bck :)

Comment: The openmanage CD isn't going to help you install the OS...

Comment: what cd do i need to install the os then? other than the os install cd?!

Comment: http://www.cs.indiana.edu/~stailey/OpenManage_IS_UG/faq.htm says that it's bootable and helps setup the system?!

Comment: If it contains the server assistant, it will help. Some openmanage cds only have the management software on them.